# Create 3-4 editable Pages in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site

I want to create SharePoint Site with simple 3-4 Pages that is like Homepage,About Us,Contact Us and Products.

User/Owner Should Login in site and can Change the contents of these pages.

My questions are :-
1. How do I create such Pages on SharePoint ? 
2. Where to store custom data - should I use List or Database ? 
3. How to display Contents from Stored Location when the page is open  ?

Comment: Do you want to create a public facing site? The you may want to create a Publishing site. The data will be stored in a Publishing Pages Library. Pages can be edited by authorised users and can undergo an approval process to be published for public viewing.

Please explain how custom data fits in with the concept of four pages with text information. 
Please explain how "Contents from Stored Location" fits in.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? It is important in giving you a proper answer.

Comment: i used sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

If the data is unique to each page (eg. You dont need the "Contact us" information and the "Products" information on the same page) then I'd simply create a standard site for each. 
From the homepage click Site Actions > New Site, for each one you want to create. 
I would store all the data in sharepoint lists and then display these on each page using the relevent webparts. 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a wiki library or a publishing pages library should meet your needs.  On either of these page types you can display webparts if you'd like.  The pages library will probably require you to create a page layout using SP Designer and a content type that matches what data you want to store on the page.